# Win7 MCE seems unable to play ripped DVDs

Tags: windows-7, dvd, windows-media-center, ripping

I'm running Windows 7 and am using mymovies.dk to rip the dvds to my harddrive. However, playback isn't watchable as the picture is very stuttery and blocky, only shots that show the same image for a few seconds get shown properly.

The dvd's are ripped as the straight folder structure and if played in XBMC are fine. I've tried installing both the cccp-project.net and latest div-x codecs, but that doesn't seem to have helped. I'd like to stick with MCE as it has a high WAF (wife acceptance factor).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

TRY VLC Player works with most every format and i would also like to suggest [link DVDecrypter](http://www.dvddecrypter.org.uk/) to rip your dvd's and if it is HD or having problems with riping that one. try [dvdfabHD](http://www.dvdfab.com/free.htm) hopefuly one of these solutions can help you..

Answer (score 0):

I have DVDs ripped to .iso which I play in 7mc. I have installed MediaBrowser (highly recommend) which mounts the .iso using Daemon Tools (automatically) and plays it. I believe it also plays ripped DVDs.

Answer (score 0):

[AnyDVD](http://www.slysoft.com) does good job of converting the DVD files to something [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr) can read.  You can pick the output format in Handbrake, but I usually pick something that Apple products can read so that I can also get the files on an iPhone through iTunes. THe all play through Windows 7 MC just fine.

Its worth it to pay for AnyDVD in my opinion.

You might also find [Jeff's post](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/12/easy-efficient-hi-def-video-playback.HTML) on some of his video playback escapades useful too.